# Multiple Dynamic Segments in a Single Resource in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

Is there a way to have multiple dynamic segments with a single resource? My use case is to avoid letting the user hit index routes.

Example:

```
this.resource('tracks', { path: 'albums/:album_id/tracks/:tracks_id' });
```

And I'd like to avoid the user from hitting the following routes:

```
albums/:album_id
albums/:album_id/tracks
albums/:album_id/tracks/:track_id
```

Routes:

```
this.resource('albums', { path: 'albums' }, function(){
  this.resource('album', { path: '/:album_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('tracks', { path: 'tracks' }, function(){
      this.resource('track', { path: '/:track_id' });
    });
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Defining Your Routes](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/)

> NOTE: If you define a resource using this.resource and do not supply a
>   function, then the implicit resource.index route is not created.

Comment: I assume you found a solution, because this is definitely possible.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to use Ember's nested routes. Each route having its own dynamic segment.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('albums', { path: '/albums' }, function () {
        this.resource('album', { path: ':album_id' }, function () {
            this.resource('tracks', { path: 'tracks' }, function () {
                this.resource('track', { path: ':track_id' });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

If you want to show the user the first track immediately after clicking an album, you could use a redirect.

```
App.AlbumRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    afterModel: function (album, transition) {
        this.transitionTo('track', {album_id: album.id, track_id: album.tracks[0].id});
    },
});
```

Check out the docs on redirection: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/

Comment: We ended up redirecting to the index page of the application when hitting the index routes in the question directly via the URL. What we wanted to avoid was creating these index routes (AlbumsIndexRoute, etc...) since our UX is a bit different. It would be nice if we could specify if wanted those index routes when we define a resource.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness sake, the index routes aren't necessary, they are just a freebie convenience if you define them, if you don't define them it won't go to them.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eMofowUQ/1/edit

And you can define multiple slugs in a single path and go directly to it, just note you'll only have a single model for that single resource, so you'll have to deal with that.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eMofowUQ/2/edit

Comment: This is a great explanation. Your first point made sense, but since we have nested resources, Ember.js automatically creates Index routes. So we couldn't go the first route. The second route made sense but we needed two models (possibly more later on).

Comment: I was hoping there was an easier way but we had to basically create a redirect on the index routes.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for us was to use the following:

```
App.AlbumsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    redirect: function(){ 
        this.transitionTo('dashboard');
    } 
});
```