# Neither model or setupController called on page refresh, but the correct route amd template chosen

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I have an ember route like this;

```
this.resource('searchauctions', { path: 'section/search/:date_one/:date_two/:some_id});
```

When using link-to I can move into this route with no problems. When I refresh the page and check ember inspector I am in the correct route, the correct controller and the model has an object with the values I would expect, but the model or setupController hooks are not called so I can't capture the values to re run the search in order to populate the template.

My controller has an action on it which updates an array on the model, the gets the search values and uses:

```
var urlString = '/section/search/' + model.date_one + '/' + model.date_two + '/' + model.some_id;
window.history.pushState({}, null, urlString.trim());
```

to update the url. Is this what is causing the problem?

Basically refreshing the page is not calling the hooks I would expect, but it is choosing the correct template to use.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this problem but maybe this part of the video would be helpfull... https://youtu.be/1QHrlFlaXdI?t=18m2s

Comment: @licanbur Thanks, that's the exact behaviour I would expect to happen, I just can't figure out what I'm doing differently!

Comment: is this of an help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165072/is-resource-nesting-the-only-way-to-enable-multiple-dynamic-segments ?  also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410838/multiple-dynamic-segments-in-a-single-resource-in-ember-js