# How to define two ember routes with same name with different number of query params?

Tags: ember.js

I have defined two ember routes as follows.

```
export default Router.map(function () {

    this.route('stock-overview', {path: '/:lan/stock-overview/:companyId'});
    this.route('stock-overview', {path: '/:lan/stock-overview/:exchange/:symbol'});
```

same name but different number of params. but when i add `link-to` helper as follows it gives an error saying.

```
<li>{{#link-to 'stock-overview' 'en' '70'}}Stock Overview{{/link-to}}</li>
<li>{{#link-to 'stock-overview' 'en' 'exchange' 'someSymbol'}}Stock Overview{{/link-to}}</li>

Console Error: 
Uncaught Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: stock-overview
```

How can I handle this situation.? My ember version is:`1.11.1`
Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can define single route and then provide default value for symbol so that it wont be shown in URL. `{{#link-to 'stock-overview' 'en' '70' ''}}`..

Comment: In that case how can I correctly identify exchange/companyId?

Comment: Sorry. I thought you are talking about `queryParams` since you mentioned in question.So to answer your question I would suggest you to use [queryParams](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/query-params/)  instead of [dynamicSegment](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) for `symbol. currently what you are trying is not feasible afaik

Answer (score 0):

I'm not %100 sure, but if i'm not wrong, you can only have one model for a route.

IMO, it would be better for you to do this with [nested route](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-routes).

**Update:**

I found some Q-A's from SO. Maybe those can be helpful for you:

- [Is resource nesting the only way to enable multiple dynamic segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165072/is-resource-nesting-the-only-way-to-enable-multiple-dynamic-segments)
- [Multiple Dynamic Segments in a Single Resource in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410838/multiple-dynamic-segments-in-a-single-resource-in-ember-js) (see also Kingpin2k's answer)